# Fast method of reading binary file contents not working correctly

Tags: java, android, io, bin

I'm creating an Android app that needs to read a ~5 mb binary file in order to use the part of speech tagger from Apache OpenNLP. I tried a fairly circuitous route to read the file quickly, using a ByteBuffer and a custom ByteBufferInputStream class. I thought I was doing it correctly, but when I checked the POSModel that is returned by the method it turns out to be 'null'. What is supposed to happen is that a ByteBuffer reads the info from the binary file, and then gives that as an InputStream to the POSModel constructor.

Here's the code for getting the part of speech model from the binary file:

```
public POSModel setupPOSModel() {
        ByteBufferInputStream modelIn = null;
        POSModel model = null;
        try {
            InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.en_pos_maxent);
            byte[] b = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);

            modelIn = new ByteBufferInputStream(buf);
            model = new POSModel(modelIn);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Model loading failed, handle the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelIn != null) {
                try {
                    modelIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
//at this point 'model' is null
        System.out.println("POS MODEL: " + model);
        return model;
    }
```

And here's the code for the ByteBufferInputStream, which I got from another Stack Overflow question:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ByteBufferInputStream extends InputStream {

    private int bbisInitPos;
    private int bbisLimit;
    private ByteBuffer bbisBuffer;

    public ByteBufferInputStream(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        this(buffer, buffer.limit() - buffer.position());
    }

    public ByteBufferInputStream(ByteBuffer buffer, int limit) {
        bbisBuffer = buffer;
        bbisLimit = limit;
        bbisInitPos = bbisBuffer.position();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (bbisBuffer.position() - bbisInitPos > bbisLimit)
            return -1;
        return bbisBuffer.get();
    }
}
```

Now, my final goal is simply to read "en_pos_maxent" binary file as fast as possible (currently, using a regular InputStream, it takes about 20 seconds), so if there is a better way than my roundabout way to get the file contents quickly using a ByteBuffer then that alternate method could work too.

Update:

Here's the stack trace for the exception thrown by the method:

```
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err: java.util.zip.ZipException: CRC mismatch
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readAndVerifyDataDescriptor(ZipInputStream.java:215)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:164)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:245)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:179)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel.<init>(POSModel.java:105)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.newssummary.MainActivity$override.setupPOSModel(MainActivity.java:245)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.newssummary.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
08-08 14:59:38.220 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.newssummary.MainActivity.setupPOSModel(MainActivity.java:0)
08-08 14:59:38.221 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.newssummary.MainActivity$4.doAsync(MainActivity.java:190)
08-08 14:59:38.221 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.newssummary.MainActivity$4.doAsync(MainActivity.java:182)
08-08 14:59:38.221 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at com.arasthel.asyncjob.AsyncJob$4.run(AsyncJob.java:91)
08-08 14:59:38.221 2735-3351/com.newssummary W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: does the `POSModel` initialization throw an `IOException`? can you share the stack trace?

Comment: When you are calling toByteArray you already copied the whole stream to an array.

Comment: Get rid of the `ByteBufferInputStream`, and the `ByteBuffer`, and the byte array, and pass the *original* stream directly to the constructor of `POSModel`. If it isn't fast enough, wrap it in a `BufferedInputStream`. All these extra shenanigans are just wasting time and space, and introducing bugs.

Comment: @EJP I did all of the things you suggested; the thing is, if I just use a regular InputStream it takes about 20 seconds to load. Since the final result for this project is an app that ideally would be used by people, I can't have the program taking 20 seconds to load when the user opens it.

Comment: @oldrinb I added the stack trace.

Comment: You can also use the java ByteArrayInputStream instead of your ByteBufferInputStream.

Comment: @Me2 That's the time it takes to read the input stream. Adding more code around that process cannot possibly make it faster, and adding code with bugs in it is just wasting time shooting alligators when the objective was to drain the swamp.

Answer (score 0):

Without you going into greater detail about the exceptions thrown by the `POSModel` initialization, I can only suggest a bit of simplification here to avoid `ByteBuffer` entirely. Consider using a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) as follows:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

final byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
final InputStream memstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

model = new POSModel(memstream);
```

Alternatively, consider using a [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) instead of manually reading the entire resource into a large buffer first.

---

The exception trace you've shared suggests there's some corruption occurring to the model data, either in the actual resource data or as a side effect of `IOUtils.toByteArray` or your `ByteBufferInputStream` implementation. Try using `ByteArrayInputStream` and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I didn't use a BufferedInputStream is that the speed of the BufferedInputStream was virtually identical to the speed of a regular InputStream.

Comment: @Me2 Which indicates that the input stream was already buffered.

Comment: Reading a 5mb resource takes nothing close to 20 seconds. The issue you have seems to be internal to POSModel, and no matter what you do with the buffer, won't help.

Comment: @lionscribe perhaps it's finishing sooner because it's throwing an exception earlier :)

Comment: @oldrinb The ByteBufferInputStream made the program significantly faster, but I'll look into the actual POSModel file for whatever is slowing it down. Thanks!

Comment: @Me2 it's going 'significantly faster' because the `POSModel` initialization is failing relatively quickly during ZIP decompression. somehow your `POSModel` is corrupted so be aware. using `ByteArrayInputStream` is better than `ByteBufferInputStream` and `ByteBuffer.wrap`, though, as a matter of maintainability